# How to move the cursor into empty space? Virtual space?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

I use Microsoft visual studio code.
I am moving the cursor by pressing the arrow keys, but when I try to move it down at the end of a line, it moves to the beginning of the next line.

What I want is for the cursor to move to the same position on the next line.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since vscode does not support the concept of "virtual spaces" there is no built-in way to do it.  I found one extension that does do it though:

[fake-virtual-space](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AntonKhorev.vscode-fake-virtual-space)

There are some limitations but it does do what you want.  In the demo below I am only using the up and down arrow keys to move the cursor to a new, previously empty, line.

[image: demo of fake virtual space being added by cursor movement]

Comment: I trired this, however it causes some errors in my working space.
I'll find an another editor instead